# What does ? mean when used as a field initializer in Toit?

Tags: toit

I'm writing code in Toit. I've seen a few uses of `?` to initialize fields in classes. What does that mean?

```
class Point:
  x ::= ?
  y ::= ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Toit, you can use `?` as the field initializer to indicate that the field will have its value set in the constructor of the class. The `Point` code in the question is incomplete without a constructor and the compiler will tell you:

```
error: Field 'x' must be initialized in a constructor
  x ::= ?
  ^
error: Field 'y' must be initialized in a constructor
  y ::= ?
  ^
```

You must provide a value for the two fields in the constructor before the system can create the `Point` instance for you. You can achieve this through a constructor that sets the fields directly from the provided arguments:

```
class Point:
  x ::= ?
  y ::= ?
  constructor .x .y:
```

or you can compute a value for the fields in the initializer and assign to them:

```
import math

class Point:
  x/float ::= ?
  y/float ::= ?
  constructor r t:
    x = r * (math.cos t)
    y = r * (math.sin t)
```